# Mahapps.Metro : The attachable property WindowCommands was not found in type MetroWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I thought i'd try out some WPF Metro using [Mahapps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) and have come across the error:

> The attachable property WindowCommands was not found in type MetroWindow

I have included the packages from nuget and have the following xaml:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
        <Controls:WindowCommands>
            <Button Content="settings" />
        </Controls:WindowCommands>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>


    <Controls:MetroContentControl>
        <Button Content="Blah" Height="20" Width="150" />
    </Controls:MetroContentControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

and the code behind:

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow 
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to get the title bar like the one on the documentation [here](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your project.

Your code seems OK. It seems you might have not build your project after the references were added.
Does this error still persist?

Comment: It seems to work on my other pc's so guess that my VS is borked (unsupprisingly)

Answer (score 2):

That code works well, you just did a little misspelling.
Change that:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />`

by that:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />`